# Should I inform my company's HR whether I will be relocating once I have already quit?

Tags: human-resources, resignation

I quit today and a lady from HR emailed me to ask if I would be staying in the country after my last day with the company. I fail to see why they need that information.

Comment: were you sponsored by your company?

Comment: That seems strange. On the face of it I would ignore the email.  Of course, there could be more to the story - it could relate to national visas in some way.

Comment: If the OP did have a visa sponsored by the company, then more than likely the company would be required to notify immigration as soon as employment ends - irrespective of whether the individual has made any other arrangements to stay in the country or not. As such, the company doesn't need to know - they just tell immigration "X individual, who we sponsored a visa for, no longer works here".

Comment: @brhans You are correct that his employer doesn't need to do anything other than report they have left. It might however have been a courtesy. Looking at UK law (as an example) when they notify immigration a sponsored employee has left it starts a 'curtailment' process. This reduces the length of time left on the visa. I don't know if this is true everywhere but they might have been wanting to give the OP a heads up about his status.

Comment: When in doubt, just ask them "Why?"  There may be a perfectly reasonable reason, but the only way to know for sure is to ask them.  If the reason seems shady or unnecessary, you can decline to answer at that time.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, in general you should provide a contact address.

It depends on the laws of each country, but in most cases there are always important documents, the last pay check, references (and more like these, you get the idea...) that can only be produced (and mailed to you) after you leave.

Comment: Right. It could be that the person literally just meant "will your mailing address change".   The best response here would be "I'm uncertain at this time, do you need a mailing address?"  or "I'm uncertain at this time. Why did you need to know?"

Comment: ...year-end tax paperwork, immigration documents if they sponsored your visa, retirement-plan statements... all sorts of reasons they might need to contact you, many of which are for *your* benefit more than theirs.